# Yii framework - Populate a checkBoxList

Tags: php, yii, checkboxlist

I want to create a form in yii with a checkboxlist populated by a related data. The form is the following :

```
<div class="form">   
    <?php 
        $form = $this->beginWidget('GxActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'groupeAdd-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'id_groupe', array('hidden' => true, 'value' => $_GET['id'])); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <label><?php 
            echo "Sélectionner les contacts à ajouter"; 
            ?>
        </label>
        <?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'id_contact', GxHtml::encodeEx(GxHtml::listDataEx(Contact::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)), true, true)); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo GxHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Ajouter')); ?>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

But when sending the form, I get an exception.

> ```
> Please fix the following input errors:
> Id Contact must be a number.
> ```

Looking at the source code of my HTML file, I remarked a hidden `input` field which may be at the origin of the problem. How to remove this field, if it is the solution? Please help.

This is the result of `$_REQUEST` dump.

The content of the file is the following, as I checked all the boxes :

```
Array
(
[r] => groupe/AddMember
[id] => 1
[EtreMembre] => Array
    (
        [id_groupe] => 1
        [id_contact] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
            )

    )

   [yt0] => Ajouter
)
```

Comment: I don't think it is a hidden field problem. You can easily test this by checking all the checkboxes. If the problem still exists it's not the hidden field.
I think you should replace the listDataEx() part with something like:
GxHtml::listDataEx(Contact::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'))

Comment: Check what **GxHtml::encodeEx** method returns , it must return an array with integer index i.e. the id for the values.

Comment: @anwerjunaid, `print_r(GxHtml::encodeEx(GxHtml::listDataEx(Contact::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)), true, true));` shows the following : `Array ( [1] => Name1 [2] => Name2 [3] => Name3 )`.

Comment: This is correct and expected, make sure no hidden field overriding your checkbox.

Comment: @user3535256, checking all the boxes doesn't avoid the exception. It remains. On the other hand `listData()` no more solved the problem.

Comment: dump the $_REQUEST at submit and check it.

Comment: You don't need to put the result as answer , just edit your question,
And your problem is clear **id_contact** must be an integer but you are passing an array, use foreach loop to insert the rows.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. Thanks to you all.